youtube-download-cli: inaccessible or not found
So I'm trying to code a mobile app that downloads youtube videos. And it works great on a computer. But, it depends on a package called youtube-download-cli (can be found on github here). I added it as a requirement, but whenever I run the app, it says youtube-download-cli: inaccessible or not found. I installed the requirements, and it says it successfully installed youtube-download-cli. I'm using briefcase and BeeWare. Help!!
Thanks in advance,
SmallCoder14

It's unclear exactly how you're using youtube-download-cli. The documentation doesn't mention any public API, only a command-line executable, which won't work on Android. Perhaps you should try another YouTube downloader library which supports being embedded in another program.

@mhsmith, Thanks. I ended up just using pytube. Now I;m getting an age restriction error
